# Command line argument in simulation

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to input a comandline argument to set values for a and r from the comandline. I'm really new to python so any help would be appreciated. 
a = 1/(# days infected)
r = infectiousness of disease

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys


population = 763
Scur = population -1    # number of people susceptible
Icur = 1                # number of people infected
Rcur = 0                # number of people recovered

trans_const = 0.00218   # infectiousness of disease r = kb/N
recov_rate = 0.5        # recovery rate a = 1/(# days infected)
simlength = 20          # number of days in simulation

SIRarray = np.zeros((simlength+1,3)) # using floats as ~% of popn
SIRarray[0,:] = Scur, Icur, Rcur     # record initial values

for i in range(1, simlength+1):
    new_infected = trans_const * Scur * Icur   # = rSI
    new_recovered = recov_rate * Icur          # = aI

    Scur = Scur - new_infected
    Icur = Icur + new_infected - new_recovered
    Rcur = Rcur + new_recovered

    SIRarray[i,:] = Scur, Icur, Rcur

print("SIR Model Simulation") 
print("Scur\t\tIcur\t\tRcur")
print("----------------------------------------")
for i in range(len(SIRarray)):
    print("{0:.2f}\t\t{1:.2f}\t\t {2:.2f}".format(SIRarray[i,0],
                                           SIRarray[i,1], SIRarray[i,2]))
a = int(sys.argv[1])
r = int(sys.argv[1])


plt.plot(SIRarray[:,0], "b")
plt.plot(SIRarray[:,1], "r")
plt.plot(SIRarray[:,2], "g" )
plt.title("SIR model parameters r = " + str(trans_const) + " a = " + str(recov_rate))
plt.xlabel("Number of People")
plt.ylabel("Number of People")
plt.legend(['Susceptible People', 'Infected', 'Recovered', 'y = 4x'],
loc='upper left')
plt.legend(['Susceptible People', 'Infected', 'Recovered', 'y = 4x'],
loc='upper left')
plt.savefig('SIR Model Simulation')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I do not see where you are trying to use `a` and `r` after getting them as input. Also, could you include how you are running the program since what you have written there is for runtime command-line arguments. If you want interactive input with a prompt, in python, use `input()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: It can help with stackoverflow questions, and general debugging, if you reduce the problematic part of your code down to a simple use case. Here meaning, try to run a small program that only takes an input and prints it as output. For example: `print(input())` or `print(sys.argv)` as the entire program.